# Problem with selection rectangle

Tags: qt, listview, qt4, symbian, nokia

I am trying to make a customized listview in QT for the Symbian OS.
However, I am facing some problems: I am able to draw everything like icons, text etc.. wherever I wish.

However, it is not getting selected by default.

To do selection, I need to draw the rectangle manually.
It could be a problem if they got changed or some other stuff took place, however.

How would I get the default selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to call the base class paint. Once the overridden function gets over, I need to call the base class paint.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call the setFocus() method which your listview inherits from QWidget.

Comment: Hey i am sorry.. i found answer.. its we need to call the base call paint once the inherited paint function gets over,,
i just did it,,. i got default selection rect.